# Mongoose plugin changes in pre 'save' and pre 'findOneAndUpdate' hooks do not get persisted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node-express application that connects to MongoDB using the Mongoose library.
But I'm having problems getting my custom Mongoose plugins to bring changes to the documents before they are saved to the database.
Here is how I define my plugin:

```
const requestContext = require('request-context');

module.exports = (schema, options) => {
    schema.pre('save', next => {
        const author = requestContext.get('request').author;
        this._createdBy = author.sub;
        this._owner = author.sub;
        this._groupOwner = author.group;
        next();
    });
    schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', next => {
        const author = requestContext.get('request').author;
        this._lastEditAt = Date.now();
        this._lastEditBy = author.sub;
        next();
    });
}
```

Then I add it to the schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const trace = require('../plugins/trace');

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    Text: String,
    category: String,
    _createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    _lastEditAt: Date,
    _createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    _lastEditBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    _owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },_groupOwner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Group'
    }
});

PostSchema.plugin(trace);
exports.schema = PostSchema;
exports.model = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

In my Express controller:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const Post = require('../model/post').model;

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post(req.body);
    post.save()
        .then(() => res.json(post))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});

router.put('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, {new: true})
        .then(post => res.json(post))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});
```

The pre hooks defined by the plugin are triggered but the changes they bring are never persisted to the database. Is this a bug in Mongoose plugin system.
I have tried with `Mongoose@4.13.9` and `Mongoose@5.3.3` but none works.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue during all the week-end.
Luckily I have found the origin of the problem.
First: I was using arrow functions for my hook methods, which changes the context of the `this` keyword.
So I had to define my hook functions using the old es5 function syntax as follows:

```
const requestContext = require('request-context');

module.exports = (schema, options) => {
    schema.pre('save', function(next) {
        const author = requestContext.get('request').author;
        this._createdBy = author.sub;
        this._owner = author.sub;
        this._groupOwner = author.group;
        next();
    });
}
```